# How to distinguish the Google Pixel phone from Verizon?

Tags: google-pixel, verizon

How to distinguish the Google Pixel phone from Verizon? I do not see any Verizon app in there, maybe because it has reset once?

Comment: Locked and non-unlockable (not through the usual fastboot command, anyway) bootloader should be a quick giveaway.

Comment: @AndyYan Can you elaborate a little more?  The phone is already unlocked when I bought the phone online from ebay not from store, but I have no idea where is it from... :(

Comment: I don't know of another way, sorry... But if it's unlocked and has no Verizon wares in it, then even if it's from VZW, the previous owner just flashed it back to the normal version, making it no different from that.

Comment: Isn't the simple answer whether or not OEM Unlocking option is usable in Developer Options or not? I believe on the Verizon version it is grayed out and cannot be switched on.

Comment: @acejavelin hmm don't have one to test.  Do have an older Nexus.  Could you add a picture if you have one?

Comment: @William I don't have one... But I tried helping someone a few months ago unlock their bootloader (thought it would be easy) and that option was grayed out and could not be turned on at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading online and this is what I have gathered.

You need to check the following using the [CID Getter app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tritonsoft.cidgetter).

[image]

Alternatively, it has been mentioned you can also check the OEM Unlocking option [here](https://us.v-cdn.net/6030075/uploads/attachments/Screenshot_2017-05-30-13-26-37.jpg).  If it is grayed out it isn't available for your phone.

[image]